# Publish files on Azure DevOps that can be downloaded by machine without access to DevOps account

Tags: azure-devops, download, upload

We need to publish installer files on Azure DevOps. They need to be downloaded on demand on our customer's machine. These machines do not have access to our Azure DevOps account.

Is there some cloud location associated with Azure DevOps? We do not want a service, but a location to store downloadable files.

Comment: Sorry your right I should have accepted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no". You'll need to decide on an external hosting method and set up a pipeline to publish your installer binaries to that external host. Azure blob storage is a reasonable candidate; you can upload the installer and generate a URI with a SAS token to allow them to download while still keeping people who *don't* have the SAS token from having access.

There are dozens of other potential solutions to the problem, but choosing one is going to be highly dependent on numerous factors that would require an extended discussion between all the parties involved. For example, FTP/SFTP may be acceptable -- it depends on if your customer already has that capability in place and if they have the appropriate process in place to make files from that FTP server available to the users who need them.